# Existence and uniqueness of solutions to a piecewise differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a first-order ODE of the form

$\frac{dy}{dx}=g(y)$,

where $g$ is given, but $g$ may be only piecewise continuous, being undefined at the points of discontinuity. We require the solution to be continuous.

Am I right in thinking that the standard results for existence and uniqueness basically carry over? Is it necessary that $g$ be well behaved near the discontinuous points, e.g., not singular? Is there standard terminology, or standard ways of reducing this type of diffeq to a more standard form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let's consider the situation where there is one discontinuity of $g$, at $y = 0$, you take an initial condition $y(t_0) = y_0$ where 
$y_0 < 0$, and $g(y) > 0$ for $y_0 \le y < 0$, and with this initial condition
the solution $y = \varphi_1(t) \to 0$ as $t \to t_1-$.  Then we have
$$ \int_{y_1}^0 \dfrac{dy}{g(y)} = t_1 - t_0$$
Thus $g$ may have a singularity at $0$, but if $1/g$ is not integrable on $[y_1, 0)$ you'll never get to $y=0$.

To continue past $t=t_1$, you need a solution $y = \varphi_2(t)$ of your differential equation
in the region $y > 0$ such that $\varphi_2(t) \to 0$ as $t \to t_1+$.
Let's say that has $\varphi_2(t_2) = y_2$ where $y_2 > 0$ and $t_2 > t_1$.
Of course we need $g(y) > 0$ for $0 < y < y_2$, and

$$ \int_0^{y_2} \dfrac{dy}{g(y)} = t_2 - t_1 $$

so that if $g(y)$ has a singularity at $0$, $1/g$ must be integrable there.